# How to use terraform for objects where the state needs to time out

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

We currently use the terraform resource `google_bigquery_job` to execute one off DML statements such as:

```
create or replace table_a as(
select
 *,
 null as new_column
from table_a
)
```

This allows for us to keep a git history of any one off commands that have been executed. The issue is that the job_id on the Google end which terraform looks for has a 6 month time out. This then causes the resource to attempt to be created again since the tf plan identifies that there is a missing resource vs the config files. Is there a way to execute an apply once on a file, and then prevent terraform for checking its physical state again?

Comment: why dont you put your DML statement in a routine so that it remains in the state and have visibility too

Comment: Hi @Prany thank you, I will have a look at this